# What is wrong with these functions for sending/receiving a string over a socket?

Tags: c++, sockets

I am trying to write two methods for sending and receiving strings over a socket. This is to clean up legacy code for Windows, which uses `send` and `recv` sprinkled all over the place, so that I wanted to put it into function to clean up a little. You can see what I came up with below. Unfortunately as soon as I use the function in my code like this:

```
std::string buffer = receiveStringFromSocket();
```

and

```
rc = sendStringToSocket(buffer);
```

my code locks up and doesn't even hit a break-point anymore.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am having a hard time debugging this, since I am not very familiar with C/C++. It could be that the error is somewhere else in the tangled mess that is this code-base.

**sendStringToSocket**:

```
int sendStringToSocket(std::string sendString)
{
    char sendBuffer[1024];
    memset(sendBuffer, 0, sizeof(sendBuffer)); //Clear the buffer
    //sendString.copy(sendBuffer, sendString.length());
    strcpy(sendBuffer, sendString.c_str());
    cout << "string buffer content:" << endl << cout.write(sendBuffer,sendString.length()) << endl;
    rc = send(acceptsocket, sendBuffer, sizeof(sendBuffer)-1, 0);
    return rc;
}
```

**receiveStringFromSocket**:

```
std::string receiveStringFromSocket()
{
    char receptionBuffer[1024];
    memset(receptionBuffer, 0, sizeof(receptionBuffer)); //Clear the buffer
    rc = recv(acceptsocket, receptionBuffer, sizeof(receptionBuffer)-1, 0); 
    string str(receptionBuffer);
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Great, your mention of a breakpoint indicates that you know how to use a debugger. Instead of waiting until you hit a breakpoint, just step through the entire code, one line at a time, until you determine where it gets stuck. There's nothing stated in the question that indicates there's an issue with any of the two shown functions.

Comment: You are sending more data than you should, and you are copying more data into the received string than you should.

Comment: For the sending: What if the string is larger than the buffer? Why send the whole buffer even if the string is just a single character? You could just call `send` with `sendString.c_str()` directly, sending `sendString.size() + 1` bytes (the +1 for the terminator), thereby not needing a temporary buffer at all and not needing the copying.

Comment: do not use strcpy, it can cause with buffer overflow

Comment: I should have mentioned. Both client-side to communicate with a server. If that matters. Also: I know I should check for overflows, but since I know the lengths of the strings/char arrays being sent on both sides I am blissfully ignoring this. Given these considerations and just focusing on the two functions: Should they work? @JoachimPileborg Thanks for the suggestion - I will try that.

Comment: the posted code is `c++` not `c`.  Please remove the `c` tag from the question.

Comment: N.B Buffers need to be char arrays of a given number of bytes, e.g. char [1024] buff;

Answer (score 0):

For sending: the main issue is that you don't need a sendbuffer: you can pass `sendString.c_str()` to the `send()`  function.  The problems introduced by using the sendbuffer are described in the comments.

For receiving: you must check the return value for `recv()`.  There's no telling what can go wrong on the network.

Combination: There is no guarantee in TCP (assuming that is what you're using) that the number of bytes per send-call will be the same as what you will receive per recv-call.  You have to implement some check to see whether all needed bytes are received (simplest: send and check null-byte).  This will probably not be noticed for strings under 50 bytes, but at some point, you will be missing part of the string.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestions. I will try that. I was basically working with what I had in the code-base. As deviantfan suggested, I will definitely have to read up on socket communication. If I don't, I guess I will be worsening the situation more than it already is.

Comment: You claim that OP does not need a sendbuffer is incorrect, in the logic that was choosen he does need that buffer.

Comment: @slava: that is not my experience: `sendString.c_str()` can be used directly. http://linux.die.net/man/2/send doesn't contradict this.  Any references?

Comment: @stefaanv problem is not if `c_str()` can be used directly or not. Problem that OP chosen to always send 1023 bytes (zero padded), so if string length less that that he cannot use `c_str()` directly.

Comment: @slava: I assumed that's one of the errors.  It's up to him to decide.

Comment: @stefaanv your assumption is wrong and I do not know what is based on. Code clearly shows logic chosen to send/receive string as a buffer fixed length.

Comment: @Slava That assumption is normal and it is based on efficiency among ther things. Why would you send trailing null data that isn't part of the message? And there is no such thing as receiving a fixed length in TCP.

Comment: @TCP "Why would you send trailing null data that isn't part of the message?" That's one of the method to send a string over network. If it is efficient or not it is up to OP to decide. Code clearly shows that approach and saying that you can use `c_str()` without even mention that you have to change your approach is definitely misleading.

Comment: Yep, we agree that it is up to OP to decide.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is that neither send nor recv does not guarantee data sent/received would be the same size you expect. So you would need functions which relay on that fact. For example:

```
void sendBuffer( const char *buff, size_t size )
{
     for( size_t sent = 0; sent != size; ) {
         int rc = send( socket, buff + sent, size - sent );
         if( rc <= 0 ) { // handle error here
         }
         sent += static_cast<size_t>( rc );
     }
}
```

you need similar one on receiving side. Having such functions it is easier to send data size before your string, it reduces data usage and simplifies code:

```
 uint32_t size = str.length();
 sendBuffer( reinterpret_cast<char *>( &size ), sizeof( size ) );
 sendBuffer( str.data(), size );
```

receiver side is similar.

Though if you decide or have to still send strings as fixed length padded buffer 1023 bytes long this function can be used for that as it is.